# Vi + Cscope: using "cscope find c function" in vim, finds multiple results, how to go next

Tags: vi, cscope

When I used this command to search functions who call this function, if there are more than one result, only the first one showed in the buffer, how do I go to the next one with a vi command or shortcut keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

> :help tag-matchlist to learn more
>
> :tnext goes to next match and
>
> :tprev goes to the previous one

Answer (score 5):

I guess your have modified your .vimrc following the instruction in this page http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cscope .

If I am right, try to delete these lines from .vimrc to see if it works :

if has('quickfix')
    set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
endif

It works for me.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information! I did followed that link. Now I commented out that line you pointed out. My question is what is the command to go to next finding then. Could you let me know? Thanks!

Comment: to go to the next item, use ":cn",

to go to previous, use ":cprev",

to go to 3rd item(say) in the list, ":cc 3"

Answer (score 1):

Try below commands
:cw
:cl
:cn
:cprev
:cc

Answer (score 0):

You can use space bar which scrolls to next page of search result , then you can use up/down arrow key to select the file you like to open by hitting enter or any key ,you also know how lines  matched for your search at the bottom , while you press space bar you will see the line matched will get decrease ,bcoz we  are scrolling the search result page .once you reaced the last page, it will again start from first .

Regards,

Tamil